# Stop BuzyBox Command Line for Loading on Start Up

Tags: command-line, startup, busybox, autostart

My computer turned itself off to protect itself from a power-surge. This has happened before many times, with nothing weird happening the next time I turned on the computer. I would press the power button, wait a minute, enter my password, and then be right back at my Desktop. This time however, something different happened. When I press the power button, I am taken to the BuzyBox command line.

To be completely honest, I am way out of my depth. My only guess for what is happening is that before there was a file that BuzyBox automatically ran when the command line was opened upon start-up, and now it does not. This seems pretty absurd to me though because the problem started after a power-surge, which primarily affects hardware, so the software should be fine. Even if this is what happened, I have no idea what file is suppose to be run, where in the directory it would be located, or the syntax that BuzyBox uses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your disk probably has been at least partially corrupted.

There are a variety of good answers on this post. I would post this as a comment, but I am 4 points away from being able to comment:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/137655/boot-drops-to-a-initramfs-prompts-busybox

Comment: Thanks so much! I tried the first suggestion in that thread and everything worked perfectly. Hopefully this will be enough to get you those last 4 points. ;)

Comment: I'm glad that worked @ETam! Don't rest yet though! You should immediately start backing up any and all valuable data. Disk corruption can continue to be a problem and you may not notice that it's destroying your data until it's too late.
After, and I repeat, AFTER you backup your data, start investigating the health of your disk. Check dmesg, do an fsck, use S.M.A.R.T tools, and consider replacing the disk if you find signs of problems.